# How can I get information about a term through JavaScript?

Tags: 2013, javascript, term

What I want to do is something like:

```
var myTerm = getTermInfo(55c6801f-78b3-485f-b811-530bec1961e9);
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you use?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to retrieve Term via SharePoint JSOM

Use [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTerm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312545(v=office.15).aspx) to get a Term object that is based on Term IDs:

```
function getTerm(termId,success,failure)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
    var term=taxSession.getTerm(termId);
    context.load(term);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
           success(term);
        },
        failure);
}
```

**Example**

```
var layoutsRoot = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/';    
$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'sp.taxonomy.js',
   function () {
      var termId = 'dff82ab5-6b7a-4406-9d20-40a8973967dd';   
      getTerm(termId,printTermInfo,printError);
});



function printTermInfo(term)
{
    console.log(String.format('Name: {0}',term.get_name()));
}

function printError(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

**Update**

Another approach for loading `sp.taxonomy.js` library:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));   
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', function () {   
    var termId = 'dff82ab5-6b7a-4406-9d20-40a8973967dd';   
    getTerm(termId,printTermInfo,printError);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this. SCRIPT5022: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with method GetTerm. File: sp.runtime.js, Line: 2, Column: 31379

Comment: Hmm..i just tested the provided code in SPO and it works just fine for me.. Probably it related with loading of sp.taxonomy.js library, the updated answer contains an alternative way for loading sp.taxonomy.js

Comment: Success! It's working now. Your original version worked, I forgot to change the term ID. Thanks.

Comment: Great, good to know! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **getTerm** method in sp.taxonomy.js library.

```
//Current Context
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
//Current Taxonomy Session    
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
var term=taxSession.getTerm("id of the term");
```

See more details here . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312545(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: How do you get the default label value from that term?