# How do you get the default label of a term through JavaScript?

Tags: 2013, javascript

Most of this code comes from an answer to a [previous question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116880/how-can-i-get-information-about-a-term-through-javascript). I'm trying to take it one step further now and get the actual default label string.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();          
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
var term = taxSession.getTerm('f06b442f-81db-4356-acc7-2c565fe3bf00'); 
var defaultLabel = term.getDefaultLabel(); 
console.log(defaultLabel);
```

Comment: I haven't done much with terms, but maybe one of these links can steer you in the right direction. The second one has a script that loops through the terms in a set and gets several values, including the label.

Comment: http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/

Comment: http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SP.Taxonomy.Term.getDefaultLabel Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312609(v=office.15).aspx) to get the default [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312461(v=office.15).aspx) for this Term based on the `LCID`:

```
function getTermDefaultValue(termId,lcid,success,failure)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
    var termDefaultValue = taxSession.getTerm(termId).getDefaultLabel(lcid);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
           success(termDefaultValue);
        },
        failure);
}
```

> Note: `SP.Taxonomy.Term.getDefaultLabel` method expects  [locale identifier
>   (LCID)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850866(v=office.15).aspx) for the label.

Example:

```
var layoutsRoot = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/';    
$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'sp.taxonomy.js',
   function () {
      var termId = 'dff82ab5-6b7a-4406-9d20-40a8973967dd';   
      getTermDefaultValue(termId,1033,printLabelInfo,printError);
});


function printLabelInfo(label)
{
    console.log(String.format('Default Label: {0}',label.get_value()));
}


function printError(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```