# Get the label name of a term through JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom, term, mms

I am trying to get the Label(Title - shown in the Navigation UI) of a term through JSOM. I have successfully got the ID of the term.

Now I got stuck in getting the Label of term using ID. I have pasted my code below. Any suggestions, what am I missing here?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  

    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/"; 
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){            
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", execOperation);
            });
        }
    );
});

function execOperation(){

    var termSetName = "ADLA";
    var locale = 1033; 
    var clientContext  = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
    var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
    var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

    clientContext.load(taxonomySession);
    clientContext.load(termStore);
    clientContext.load(termSet);
    clientContext.load(terms);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
        var chaparray={};

        var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();
            var name = spTerm.get_name();
            var id = spTerm.get_id();


    }
}, function onFailure(args) {
    alert('Error: '+args.get_message());
});
}

</script>
```

Updated:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
var taxonomySession;
var clientContext;
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/"; 
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){            
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", execOperation);
            });
        }
    );
});

function execOperation(){

    var termSetName = "ADLA";
    var locale = 1033; 
    clientContext  = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
    var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
    var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

    clientContext.load(taxonomySession);
    clientContext.load(termStore);
    clientContext.load(termSet);
    clientContext.load(terms);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
        var chaparray={};

        var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();
            var name = spTerm.get_name();
            var id = spTerm.get_id();

            getTermDefaultValue(id,1033);

        }


    },
function onFailure(args) {
    alert('Error: '+args.get_message());
});

}

function getTermDefaultValue(termId, lcid) {
    var termDefaultValue = taxonomySession.getTerm(termId).getDefaultLabel(lcid);  
}

</script>
```

Below is the image.. I need to get the "Chapter-1" text.

[image: Title]

```
var taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
                var termStore = taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;
                var termStoreGroup = termStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site);
                var termSet = termStoreGroup.CreateTermSet("ADLA");
                termSet.IsAvailableForTagging = true;
                termSet.TermStore.CommitAll();
```

Comment: Did you try spTerm.getDefaultLabel(locale) ? See this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117030/how-do-you-get-the-default-label-of-a-term-through-javascript

Comment: Unnie - Thanks for your comment. I tried the same. But the value is SP.Result {} . I am not sure how to get the Label value from this... I have updated my code in the question.. How to get the label value from this..

Comment: I have added one more image for better clarification.

Comment: Any help on this? I guess I am confusing it with label.. Is it the label value I have to get or the title value?

Answer (score 1):

When you enable Managed navigation for a site , the navigation node title is stored as a local custom property named **_Sys_Nav_Title** .

So if you want to get this data from JSOM you could use below code:

```
spTerm.get_localCustomProperties()["_Sys_Nav_Title"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Now i have got the clear idea.. I have tried your code and it works for _Sys_Nav_TargetUrl. But When I try to get "_Sys_Nav_Title", i am getting undefined. I checked in the browser console,  for spTerm.get_localCustomProperties() , object is returned with only _Sys_Nav_TargetUrl value. Am i missing something here. Please share your thoughts

Comment: I tried in another environment and it worked Unnie. Thanks a lot..Now I have one more issue, I added a new term and also modified the Navigation node title for already existing term. Both are not reflecting, though my navigation got updated with the new term and changed Node titles. Also I ran the Taxonomy update scheduler timer job to check this.  It is not updated in my Jsom code. any ideas?

Comment: Even I have deleted the termset and checked. Still the old values are coming while running the JSOM code. Even in the incognito mode , I can see the old terms.. Any ideas?

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: still i am having the same issue.. any ideas?

Comment: I deleted the old termset. It was created through code. Now i added manually another termset. Now things are working fine. I guess the problem is with the temset i created through code.     I have added the code in m question. anything wrong in my code on creating the termet?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: anyone got any ideas? anything wrong with my code, while creating the termset?